# Matching URL structures with Anemone

Tags: ruby, anemone

Right now, I'm doing the following with Anemone:

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/", :delay => 3) do |anemone|
  anemone.on_every_page do | page |
```

But I would like to do

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/", :delay => 3) do |anemone|
   anemone.on_pages_like() do | page |
```

instead to only crawl from URLs like this:

http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Apparel/1036682
http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Apparel/1040664
http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/ArtsAndCrafts/2617942011
http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/Baby/165797011

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a regular expression like this

```
/http:\/\/www.findbrowsenodes.com\/us\/.+\/[\d]*/
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But just one thing, at the beginning it includes this URL: `http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/us/p/what-are-browse-nodes` How can I modify the regex to avoid that?